# ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute when bind carousel in angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

how to get value from carousel whhich is active i was try all option

```
<carousel     [interval]="false">
<div  [(ngModel)]="mseason" value="whole-year"  (change)="mchangeSeason()" >
<slide>
    <b  >whole-year</b>
</slide>
</div>
<div  [(ngModel)]="mseason" value="spring"  (change)="mchangeSeason()" >
<slide >
    <b >spring</b>

</slide >
</div>
</carousel>
```

Comment: can you make a snippet of your program in code sandbox or stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

The ngModel directive has to be placed in an input not a div. Also where is the form tag?

Comment: i am not using form tag